# How to deal with lots of requests for "\x80d\x01\x03\x01" in cpanel/apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm seeing a lot of these in the apache error log, from many different client IPs:

`Invalid method in request \x80d\x01\x03\x01`

with "lots" i mean several per second, constantly. None of these IPs are found in the regular apache logs, so only in the error log.

Is this something to worry about, and if so, how can I repair or protect against it?

I suppose I could just make fail2ban block the IPs but that seems a bit unnecessary when I don't know what's going on.

**Edit:** Apache is serving both regular HTTP (about 100 vhosts) and SSL HTTPS (4 vhosts).

```
# uname -a
Linux xxxx 2.6.18-371.3.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 13:29:20 EST 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

# /usr/local/cpanel/cpanel -V
11.38.2 (build 12)

# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Jan 13 2013 07:13:59
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.16.6 rev9999
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:31
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/apache"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/apache/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"

# httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_authn_file.c
  mod_authz_host.c
  mod_authz_groupfile.c
  mod_authz_user.c
  mod_authz_default.c
  mod_auth_basic.c
  mod_include.c
  mod_filter.c
  mod_deflate.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_env.c
  mod_expires.c
  mod_headers.c
  mod_unique_id.c
  mod_setenvif.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_proxy.c
  mod_proxy_connect.c
  mod_proxy_ftp.c
  mod_proxy_http.c
  mod_proxy_scgi.c
  mod_proxy_ajp.c
  mod_proxy_balancer.c
  mod_ssl.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_mime.c
  mod_status.c
  mod_autoindex.c
  mod_asis.c
  mod_info.c
  mod_suexec.c
  mod_cgi.c
  mod_negotiation.c
  mod_dir.c
  mod_actions.c
  mod_userdir.c
  mod_alias.c
  mod_rewrite.c
  mod_so.c

# httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authz_host_module (static)
 authz_groupfile_module (static)
 authz_user_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (static)
 include_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 deflate_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 env_module (static)
 expires_module (static)
 headers_module (static)
 unique_id_module (static)
 setenvif_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 proxy_module (static)
 proxy_connect_module (static)
 proxy_ftp_module (static)
 proxy_http_module (static)
 proxy_scgi_module (static)
 proxy_ajp_module (static)
 proxy_balancer_module (static)
 ssl_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mime_module (static)
 status_module (static)
 autoindex_module (static)
 asis_module (static)
 info_module (static)
 suexec_module (static)
 cgi_module (static)
 negotiation_module (static)
 dir_module (static)
 actions_module (static)
 userdir_module (static)
 alias_module (static)
 rewrite_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_passthrough_module (shared)
 bwlimited_module (shared)
 frontpage_module (shared)
 security2_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: What's the output from `apachectl -S`? Do you run SSL on this system?  Seems like clients are trying to speak SSL to a non-SSL listener.

Comment: Yes there are 4 SSL virtualhosts and about 100 non-SSL vhosts.

Comment: Ok - so are there vhosts that might have screwed up SSL configurations, non-SSL vhosts on port 443, or clients that might be trying to speak SSL to a non-SSL port?

Comment: Ah..okay, that could make sense. I will have a look at that. It's all done by cpanel which I frankly find a nightmare to administrate (I prefer plain textfiles).

Comment: Ahh, yeah.. you have my sympathy on that one.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I just managed to replicate the error on my own, so at least I know which vhost it is and I'm sure I can sort it out myself from here. Thanks a lot! maybe you can make a "proper" answer here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error signifies that clients are attempting to speak SSL/TLS to a listener that is not actually running SSL.

This might be an error in configuration (missing an `SSLEngine On` for a virtual host that's intended to be SSL enabled, or is listening on port 443?).  Or it might just be a case of some wacky user trying to access `https://example.com:80`.

Unfortunately, the error doesn't provide any hints on which listener got the request - the best thing to do is to go through your configuration and make sure that all the listeners that are supposed to have SSL are speaking it correctly.

Comment: yes I manually went through the httpd.conf file, trying all servernames associated with port 443 and found the culprit hostname. When I tried accessing it in my browser (https), I got a message "Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long". I haven't solved this yet but I am sure I can figure it out. If you google this error message, you find (among other pages) this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl

Comment: @starhopper I wonder if there's some kind of problem with the certificate file it's trying to use, or something else that's causing the SSL on that listener to be broken?  If you try to talk to that listener with something like `http://example.com:443` it gives a working response, right?